# Reading a chat message should clean up the inbox

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, global-inbox

I recently activated the *Quicker Notifications* feature and also the *New Mobile UI* options. I often observe that I get notifications about missed messages, which is fine since I opted in, but they don't hide when I react on the chat messages afterwards. They should be marked as read in the inbox.

Please fix that. Thank you!

Comment: I have been facing this issue too, ever since I opted-in for new Mobile UI.